# PERL5LIB, @INC and library priority for testing

Tags: unit-testing, perl

I had some difficulties in overriding perl lib when testing perl codes when  the `.pl` or `.pm` has `use lib` or `unshift @INC`, my question is:

> Is it a bad idea to use `use lib` or `unshift @INC` in the production code since they are hard to test?  The `prove -lvr` cannot override these too.

Code `test.pl`

```
push @INC, '/push/inc/lowest_priority';
use lib "/top/priority/use/lib/second_priority";
unshift @INC, "/unshift/inc/lib/first_priority";
foreach my $inc (@INC){
    print "INC=>$inc\n";
}
```

set perl env

```
export PERL5LIB=/export/PERL5LIB/env/lib:$PERL5LIB
```

Output of `perl -I/cmd/Iinclude/lib/ test.pl`

```
INC=>/unshift/inc/lib/first_priority
INC=>/top/priority/use/lib/second_priority
INC=>/cmd/Iinclude/lib/
INC=>/export/PERL5LIB/env/lib
INC=>/usr/local/lib64/perl5
INC=>/usr/local/share/perl5
INC=>/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
INC=>/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
INC=>/usr/lib64/perl5
INC=>/usr/share/perl5
INC=>/push/inc/lowest_priority
```

Comment: I don't know what troubles you are having, but one non-obvious feature of `@INC` is that runtime changes to `@INC` with `push` and `unshift` are not available to (compile-time) `use Module ...` statements.

Comment: Also note that additions to `@INC` without using lib.pm, PERL5LIB, or the `-I` option will not include associated arch- or version-specific directories, so you should always use one of those methods to add lib directories containing modules installed from CPAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't hard-code paths unless I have no other options.

In general, you don't want to hardcode things that you can provide to your program in some other fashion so it can respond to whatever environment it's in rather than only the environment where you developed it. One of those environments could be your testing environment.

You can set the library search path from outside the program, and that makes it more flexible.

And, since you hard-code them and add them at runtime, they are going to come after anything you've set previously. Here's what happens in your setting:

- You start with the default `@INC`.
- You start to "run" your program, you start the compilation phase. It compiles the entire program before it executes run-time statements.
- As it compiles, it encounters the `use lib` and executes that pragma immediately. Now `/top/priority/use/lib/second_priority` is at the beginning of `@INC`.
- For the rest of the compilation phase, `/top/priority/use/lib/second_priority` is the first thing in `@INC`. That's where subsequent `use` calls will look for things.
- The compilation phase finishes and the program transitions into the run phase.
- It encounters the `push` and executes that. Now `/push/inc/lowest_priority` is the last element of `@INC`.
- It skips over the `use lib` because the compilation phase handled the pragma.
- It encounters the `unshift` and executes that. Now `/unshift/inc/lib/first_priority` is the first item in `@INC`.
- Subsequent `require` calls (a runtime feature) will look in `/unshift/inc/lib/first_priority` first.

I don't know where you expect to find the library you expected to load, but you have to supply the full path to it. There may be extra directories under the *lib/* that matter and you haven't accounted for.

Comment: you are right, the module would be test friendly if not use any fixed path at all. let us the ENV or each perl code take care of the lib path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your problem but [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) allows you to "manually" tune your module path. You should be able to use it to control what paths are used for your test environment.

Comment: in a `test.t`, `use local lib /git/repo` does help, Thanks!